# Xamarin forms Prism - Navigation from grid to content page. Page not shown

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, prism

In a ContentPage, I have a list of "rooms" in a ListView. When I click on one of them, it should navigate to another ContentPage with the details of the room. The OnNavigatedTo() on the ViewModel of the new page is called (apparently without errors), but the page is just not shown. It stay in the page with the list of the rooms. I test it with Android (emulator and phone) with Visual Studio 2015.

Here the XAML of the list page:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:prism="clr-namespace:Prism.Mvvm;assembly=Prism.Forms"
             xmlns:views="clr-namespace:StudentRooms.Views;assembly=StudentRooms"
             prism:ViewModelLocator.AutowireViewModel="True"
             x:Class="StudentRooms.Views.RoomsList">

  <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Rooms}"
              >
      <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
          <ViewCell>
            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Spacing="10">

              <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                <TapGestureRecognizer CommandParameter="{Binding Id}" 
                                      Command="{Binding BindingContext.RoomSelected, Source={views:RoomsList}}">
                </TapGestureRecognizer>
              </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>

              <Label Text="{Binding Name}" FontAttributes="Bold"/>
              <Label Text="{Binding Description}"></Label>
              <ProgressBar Progress="{Binding Occupancy}"/>
            </StackLayout>
          </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
      </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>  
  </StackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

Here a snippet of the ViewModel:

```
public RoomsListViewModel(INavigationService navigationService)
{
    _navigationService = navigationService;

    RoomSelected = new DelegateCommand<object>(NavigateToSelectedRoom);
}

private void NavigateToSelectedRoom(object id)
{
    //var navParams = new NavigationParameters
    //{
    //    { "RoomId", id }
    //};

    //_navigationService.NavigateAsync("RoomDetail", navParams);

    _navigationService.NavigateAsync("RoomDetail");
}
```

The detail page:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:prism="clr-namespace:Prism.Mvvm;assembly=Prism.Forms"
             prism:ViewModelLocator.AutowireViewModel="True"
             x:Class="StudentRooms.Views.RoomDetail">

  <StackLayout>
    <Label Text="AAA"></Label>
  </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

A snippet of the ViewModel:

```
public void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationParameters parameters)
{
    // on Debug I enter in this method!
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you register your pages for navigation in your App.cs/App.xaml.cs file.

Comment: it is registered. If in OnInitialized() I put: NavigationService.NavigateAsync("RoomDetail"); the page appears.

Comment: Then there may be an issue with the RoomsList page. Try placing the TapGesture on the ListView and not the StackPanel.

Comment: Probably you're right. If I put just this in the list page: 
  <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">

    <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
      <TapGestureRecognizer CommandParameter="1"
                            Command="{Binding RoomSelected}">
      </TapGestureRecognizer>
    </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
    <Label Text="AAAA BBBB" FontAttributes="Bold"/>
  </StackLayout>
It is working.
Do you know another way to link a command from an element of a list view? The only alternative I know it is with a ugly event handler but that will break MVVM. Thanks! (Prism is great!)

Comment: Actually, right now I think the ListView is broken and an ugly event handler is needed. Otherwise you would bind the COmmandParameter to the ListView.SelectedItem.Id, but it won't work the first time, but it will the second time. I think there is a bug in the ListView. You would have to try it out first to confirm.